# how do I split one row to two rows based on column value

Tags: sql

my  input is :

```
PID   PDate     col2   source1     source2
1     20200324  24      AAA        BBB
```

And i am expecting below output:

```
PID   PDate     col2   source     
1     20200324  24      AAA        
1     20200324  24      BBB
```

I tried using cross apply but not getting right output.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION is the right way to solve this:

```
SELECT PID, PDate, col2, source1 as source FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT PID, PDate, col2, source2 FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Also you can use UNPIVOT if you're using MSSQL

Comment: I am using ms sql.. I didn’t know to unpivot.